# itrerate through list of lists

Tags: java

so i have a lists within a list. i'm trying to grab the lists that are within this list. i know i can get the outer list data as seen bellow. But how do i grab the data for all the lists inside the outer list?

this is what i have:

```
public void iterateThroughList()
{
    Iterator<Test1> itr = databaseList.iterator();

    if (itr != null)
    {
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            Test1 test1= itr.next();

            System.out.println(test1.getName());
                            // set up itr2 to point to list within list??? how do i set this guy up?

            if(itr2 != null)
            {
                while(itr2.hasNext())
                {


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use for each? `for(Test1 t1 : databaseList)` or similar?

Comment: And what is the type of `databaseList`?

Comment: If your `databaseList` is a `list of list`, then your first line of code won't compile. Your iterator should be - `Iterator<List<Test1>>`. You need to post some more information in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet databaseList is a list of lists... the lists within the list contains objects of another class..

Comment: @JonSkeet defined: List<TestSuits> databaseList = new ArrayList<TestSuits>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through `Test1` in the same way, as long as `Test1` implements the `Iterable` interface.

Comment: hmm this gives me a null pointer exception.. but when i look inside databaseList i see the list inside of databaseList...